# My Windows 10 taskbar icons are messed up and I don't know how to fix it

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, icons

My Windows 10 taskbar icons are messed up and I don't know how to fix it.

Here is the screenshot, any ideas?
[image]

Symptoms:

1. All my active icons are not displayed... only 4 at a time in a slider.  This is VERY undesirable and it wasn't there before.
2. There is a big gap between time widget and right side of screen (only when 'Always show all icons' is turned off).

This happened recently, after the system restarted from a auto-update.

**UPDATE**
Paste this link in your browser, to see the problem report, as officially reported to Windows:

```
Windows-Feedback:?contextid=63&feedbackid=73f4538f-d050-4fb0-8ce8-22bac0323d59&form=1&src=2
```

Comment: This is entirely possible simply a bug in the Insider Preview build your using.  Until you can get to a stable branch not much you can do.

Comment: My system just updated again. You can see the new `release` version number in the screenshot I provided.  Still hasn't resolved the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a known bug in [Windows 10 Insider Preview Build 14271](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2016/02/24/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-14271-mobile-build-14267-1004/)

> **Known issues for PC**
>   Turning on the “always show all icons in the notification area” setting disrupts the layout of the notification area (“systray”).

If that is your situation, you will have to wait for a new build, or turn off that setting and see if it resolves the issue.

If it is not, then you should report it via the feedback methods. It is expected that some issues will come up in such preview builds, and your use of it constitutes your acceptance of that fact.

This still exists in the [latest build as of this answer (Build 14279)](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2016/03/04/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-14279/)

---

**Unconfirmed Info**

There are [some reports](http://www.tenforums.com/general-support/42961-notification-area-scroll-arrows.html) that the issue will occur regardless of the setting if there are more than 4/6 icons pinned.

Comment: I just got a new release update this morning (see screenshot) and it still hasn't resolved my issue.  Yes, the release notes suggest I turn off the "show all icons" but it has pretty much no effect, as i described in my question.

Comment: Did you read where I mentioned that the issue is still present in the latest build (14279), which is your current build? Issues don't necessarily get resolved in the build after they are discovered.

Comment: Yep, I read it carefully. Their suggested workaround does not work.  I updated my question.

Comment: Ill report problem via feedback app.

Comment: Have you tried the reported method of only showing four icons?

Comment: Yes, the 'arrows' in my screenshot will disappear if there are not more than 4 icons.   That doesn't solve my problem though since I have 12+ icons that I want to monitor.

Comment: There are multiple problem reports being posted by multiple people in the windows feedback app.  Seems hopeful that an engineer will notice and fix it.   In fact, one of them has 298 votes and its in the top-5 for reported problems.

Answer (score -1):

I just moved it to the left of the screen and then bottom again and it went back to normal.